# Why is the following-sibling expression incorrect?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

For this general structure:

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <input id="This[0].That" name="This[0].That" ng-model="item.That">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input ng-click="removeThat(item)" value="Remove">
</div>
```

why is this particular syntax invalid:

```
//input[@id='This[0].That']/following-sibling::/../input[@value="Remove"]
```

?

Comment: Is the Remove input with the ng-click value of "removeThat(item)" the only one in your dom?

Comment: It currently is (others can be added via a user control)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question, you're getting an XPath syntax error because `following-sibling::` must be followed by an NCName such as `input`:

```
`following-sibling::input`
```

However, note that the `input` elements in your sample HTML are not siblings.

You could choose the second `input` based upon the first by using the `following::` axis instead:

```
//input[@id='This[0].That']/following::input[@value="Remove"]
```

Of course, for just the small sample, a simpler XPath would suffice:

```
//input[@value="Remove"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to what kjhuges said, if your reasoning behind using the first input to anchor off of was because there were multiple 
`//input[@value='Remove']` elements, you can always use an index to find them or modifier tags

```
(//input[@value='Remove'])[index] 

//input[@value='Remove'])[last()]
```